# My staging universal link identifies and open the app but live link is not recognizing the app

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I have set up universal links to both my staging version and live version of the app respectively. Both Staging and live server hosts follow the ASSA file.

```
    {
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "TeamID.com.DC.MyappName",
        "paths": [ "*", "/" ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have given all paths and I set up branch.io and I am using the branch.io method as well. I have set both staging and live domains in Associated Domains in the signing and capabilities section. But My Problem is when I click the link from the staging hosted domain it opens the app and my breakpoint on `scendeligate` can receive the URL

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
     BranchScene.shared().scene(scene, openURLContexts: URLContexts)
     let clickedLink = userActivity.webpageURL
    print("Clicked brnach Link: \(String(describing: clickedLink))")

     let urlString = url?.absoluteString
     let component = urlString?.components(separatedBy: "=")
     print("Deeplink URL Componant: \(String(describing: component))")
}
```

but when I click the same link the domain names only change to live not even recognizing the app. it simply opens the browser.

I need help with this. I am under huge pressure to solve this issue but no clues so far. Explored many similar problems from google but not helped me so far.

my staging link -  `https://staging.aaaa.com/en-ae/accounts/verify-email/XXXXXXXXX/`

live link -  `https://www.aaaa.com/en-ae/accounts/verify-email/XXXXXXXXX/`

*When I click the staging link the app opens and I can print the webpage URL in `scenedelegate`

*When I click the live link it shows like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check AASA file is properly downloaded in device.

Comment: it's downloading..